# Complex differentiability of a function from first principles.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, derivatives

I have to show a complex function is differentiable at $0$ from first principles. For example take the function:

$f(z) = \overline{z}^2\cos{z}$.

How could I show $f(z)$ is differentiable at $0$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: "How would I do this?" To show differentiability at $z=0$, you need to analyze that the limit
$$
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}
$$
exist. Try it!

Comment: The f I have given should be diffable at 0. I had shown that functions are diffable at a point before but I don't know how this changes for the complex case!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We wish to prove $\lim_{w\to0}\frac{\overline{w}^2}{w}\cos w$ exists and evaluate it. (@mrsamy suggested this approach, but I've changed their $h$ to $w$ to emphasize the limit is in a complex variable.) The $\cos w$ factor is asymptotic to $1$, so we just want $\lim_{w\to0}\frac{\overline{w}^2}{w}$. Since $\left|\frac{\overline{w}^2}{w}\right|=|w|$, the limit is $0$ by the squeeze theorem.